# Usage of "auch mal"

Tags: usage, phrase

In what kind of situations can someone use this phrase? Does it exactly mean "once in a while" or does it imply this meaning with a bit of sarcasm?
Can one use it like in the following sentences:

> Ich gehe auch mal zu diesem Cafe.
>   Schön, das dich auch mal zu sehen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Auch mal* is one of those little idioms that are used a lot in spoken language and can have dozens if not thousands of quite different meanings depending on context. Just think of the many uses of *just*, *like* or *once* in English.

Etymologically, *auch mal* is short for *auch einmal*, so literally it translates to *also once*. (*Einmal*, literally *one time*, has been shortened to *mal*, literally *... time*.) Perhaps the most basic situation in which you can use it is when addressing someone who has been monopolising a new plaything:

> Lass mich auch mal dran! - Let me have a go at it too, for once!

In this case both words have separate, clearly distinguishable meanings:

> Lass mich dran! - Let me have a go at it!
>
> Lass mich auch dran! - Let me have a go at it, too!
>
> Lass mich mal dran! - Let me have a go at it, for once!

But note that the translation of *mal* as *for once* is overly literal and very misleading. *Mal* is a casualness marker - one of German's rich supply of discourse particles. Some of them, such as *eigentlich*, have rough equivalents in English (in this case *actually*). But *mal* doesn't, which will make it a relatively strange new concept for English speakers trying to learn German. When translating from German to English, *mal* as a casualness marker sometimes has to stay completely untranslated, and sometimes it is best translated by switching to a casual English idiom instead of the straightforward formulation used in the original:

> Schreib mir einen Brief! - Write me a letter!
>
> Schreib mir mal einen Brief! - Drop me a few lines!

Some languages use diminutives of nouns instead. Usually this works neither in German nor in English, but you can create a similar effect in English by adding an appropriate adjective to mark the casual aspect:

> Schreib mir mal einen Brief! - Write me a quick letter!

Now to your example sentences.

> Ich gehe auch mal zu diesem Café. [Note that it's much less acceptable in German than in American English to drop accents on French words. German keyboards even have a key for producing them.]

This sentence is a bit strange, since in German you don't normally go 'to' a café (meaning you stay outside), but you go 'in[to]' it. So let's fix that first:

> Ich gehe auch mal in dieses Café.

This is a sentence that might well occur in a conversation, but taken out of context it is not clear what it is supposed to mean. I can think of two interpretations:

> Ich gehe auch immer wieder mal in dieses Café. - I, too, go to this café now and then.
>
> Ich gehe dann auch mal in dieses Café. - So I'll go to this café too. [There is only a slight hint at the casualness marker in the translation: the contraction of *I will* to *I'll*.]

The second example sentence is outright ungrammatical because it mixes two constructions (and misspells one of the words involved):

> Schön, dich auch mal zu sehen!
>
> Schön, dass ich dich auch mal sehe!

In this case, *mal* works only superficially as a casualness marker. Its original meaning *[for] once* shines through under the veneer of geniality, so it's likely intended (and will be understood) like the somewhat accusatory:

> Nice to see you too, for once!

(German and English grammar are still similar enough to translate the ungrammatical blend "Schön, dass dich auch mal zu sehen!" back to English: "Nice that to see you too, for once!" This translation even works when taking the original *das* instead of *dass* seriously, as both can be translated by *that*.)

Comment: Just one small addition: In the first example of OP I guess, that *auch 'mal* is the contraction of  *auch irgendwann einmal*, e. g. in the context, that one has heard so many recommendations of it, and therefore plans to give it a try on an occasion yet to come.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of *mal* (colloquially, actually *einmal*) just indicates how often, literally *once*, but could also mean *rarely* with a bit fuzziness. That *auch* is simply *also*.

Whether that is meant with sarcasm or for real depends on the context of the situation.